# Css - Apply different CSS rule based on user input

Tags: css

I'm developing a web based source code editor. I'm thinking of adding support for themes (syntax highlighting).

```
//Default theme
.default-reserved-word
{
  background-color : red;
}

//Some other theme
.monokai-reserved-word
{
  background-color : green;
}
```

inside the editor each syntax highlightable word is surrounded by a span tag with the appropriate class:

```
....
<span class="default-reserved-word">def</span>method name
...
```

which I want to convert to (when the user clicks a "change theme" button)

```
....
<span class="monokai-reserved-word">def</span>method name
...
```

Is there a simple way of switching these CSS rules without going through all the elements and modifying the class attributes?

(FWIW, I need to support IE7+, FF3.6+)

Comment: Rather than switching the class names, I would load in a new stylesheet for each theme.

Comment: You can do this (rather tediously) using plain old Javascript, though I'd suggest a framework such as jQuery because it will make the process much simpler and faster.

Comment: @huhucat Don't forget to accept answers (not just for this question) if your question has been sufficiently answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using a different method, perhaps have a theme class on a higher parent container:

```
<div class="theme-default">
```

And then use CSS like this:

```
.theme-default .reserved-word {
    color: blue;
}
```

Whilst this method is not exactly what you've asked for it will simplify the process of changing styles, for a start you won't have to search through loads of spans, finding the current class of `theme-name` +  ' -reserved-word' (etc) and doing a string replace on them.

Comment: +1 I really like this method and it is a technique that is simple and at the same time clever.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty slick! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class name to the root element (`<html>`) and change that on use input.

```
.theme1 .reserved-word { color: red; }
.theme2 .reserved-word { color: green; }
```

and then change

```
<html class="theme1">
```

to

```
<html class="theme2">
```

with Javascript.

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery for that:

```
var elements = $('.default-reserved-word')
elements.removeClass('default-reserved-word');
elements.addClass('monokai-reserved-word');
```

Comment: Changing all elements' classes is unneeded and inefficient. Instead, you can change a higher parent's classname and declare the CSS accordingly ;)

Comment: I guess I was replying too literally to his question. I sure got my share of -1s for that :D Swapping the CSS file would indeed be a much better solution.